# How to show last 20 tweets with twitter api on Android?

Tags: android, twitter

How to show last 20 tweets with twitter api on Android OS, if tweets are old?
I've to use twitter api, but its returned only recent tweets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `twitter.getMentions()` returns by default last 20 updates. You can vary the behavior of this function using `setSinceDate` and `setSinceId` methods. So in your case you can set the date from which you want to search tweets. But remember that this function will return only 20 tweets that are started from this date.